# BackgroundTask doesn't fire

Tags: c#, uwp

My background task registers but never fires. I have tried to delete the whole project to erase all tasks, changed the name on the `TaskBuilder` class, and used different conditions. But nothing seems to work. I sometimes get an error that says it can't show me the error.

Here do I build it:

```
public async void RegisterBackgroundTask()
{
    var taskRegistered = false;
    var TaskName = "TimeTriggeredTask";

    foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
    {
        if (task.Value.Name == TaskName)
        {
            taskRegistered = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    var tommorowMidnight = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
    var timeTilMidnight = tommorowMidnight - DateTime.Now;
    var minutesTilMidnight = (uint)timeTilMidnight.TotalMinutes;
    if (!taskRegistered)
    {
        var task = RegisterBackgroundTask("TaskBuilderClass",
                                          "TimeTriggeredTask",
                                           new TimeTrigger(minutesTilMidnight, false),
                                           new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.InternetAvailable));
        await task;
        CheckPremieres();
    }
}
```

Builder method:

```
public static async Task<BackgroundTaskRegistration> RegisterBackgroundTask(String taskEntryPoint, String name, IBackgroundTrigger trigger, IBackgroundCondition condition)
{

    await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();

    var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

    builder.Name = name;
    builder.TaskEntryPoint = taskEntryPoint;
    builder.SetTrigger(trigger);
    builder.AddCondition(condition);
    BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();

    //
    // Remove previous completion status from local settings.
    //
    var settings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    settings.Values.Remove(name);

    return task;
}
```

This is the task builder class which I also added to the manifest:

```
public sealed class TaskBuilderClass : IBackgroundTask
{
    //
    // The Run method is the entry point of a background task.
    //
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {            
        //
        // Query BackgroundWorkCost
        // Guidance: If BackgroundWorkCost is high, then perform only the minimum amount
        // of work in the background task and return immediately.
        //
        var cost = BackgroundWorkCost.CurrentBackgroundWorkCost;
        var settings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        settings.Values["BackgroundWorkCost"] = cost.ToString();

        App.nHandler.CheckPremieres();
    }   
}
```

Comment: You do have the background task in a separate project and reference that project from your application? If you trigger the task from Visual Studio, it works as expected? How do you know that it never triggers and doesn't throw an exception instead? Do you have any logging in `CheckPremieres`?

Comment: No the background task i in the same Project.. i have not triggerd the task i have used the timtriger with 15min and waited.. CheckPremiers is sending a NotificationToast to the user.. I have also put a break on the Run method in the BackgroundTask class.. wich worked on MS example Project from GitHub..

Comment: *BackgroundTask* is not a *BackgroundWorker* - those are two different things (*BacgkroundWorker* is not supported in UWP). As for firing the task, please follow some guidelines: [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299100.aspx) and [here at the post](http://www.romasz.net/how-to-add-a-backgroundtask/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the task needs to be in its own Windows Runtime Component; I've always done it like this. The [Microsoft sample on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTask) also has the tasks in a separate project.

Try doing that. And don't forget to reference the newly created prject from your application. That's the thing that I most always forget.

Once you do that, I also suggest you first trigger the task from [Visual Studio Debug Location toolbar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974425.aspx#BKMK_Trigger_background_tasks), just to make sure everything is configured correctly. It should appear in the dropdown and should work correctly from here, otherwise it won't work when scheduled either.

Comment: Ok thx! I will try this, the MSDN guide i followed do not say it has to be.. but it have crosed my mind, but i did not Think it was that important.. :)

Comment: That did it. :) I can now fire the event and all. But my notification toast builder is in the original Project.. how can I access this.. becasuse i have all the info in the original Project.. :/

Comment: Im trying to create the toast.. but i have trouble accessing my SQLite in the other Project..

Comment: You can move the code to the new project, now containing the task. If you need it in your app as well, you can call it from there, since your app is referencing this project. If it's to restricting to implement this as a component, you can create a third project that is a class library and reference it from both the app and the task project. [This sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-trafficapp) has a similar structure: app, task and class library.

Comment: Both the task and the app have a common local storage, including the SQLite file. Just make sure that you reference the necessary SQLite dependencies in both projects and you should be able to open it from the task unless it is in use by the app.

Comment: It works now! I moved the creating of the toast to the Task-Project and created a copy of my SQLite class in the Task-Project aswell. I thank you so much Damir!